# Auditing Who Merged Contacts?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Is there any way to audit which admin merged duplicate contacts? I'd like to know who performed the merge, if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When contacts are merged, activities are created - you can use Search > Find Activities to search for "Contact Merged" and "Contact Deleted by Merge" activities - the "Added by" column will display the user who performed the merge.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Yes, that is helpful and I'm marking it as an accepted answer as I'm sure it's good enough for most. I was looking for a deeper type of audit that couldn't be manipulated by a user. An Activity could be edited and the Added By field value changed. Though I would hope we can trust all admins, I was looking for a more read-only type of audit log.

Comment: Another option would be to turn on advanced logging under Administer > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.), however, this takes up a tremendous amount of resources and you may not be able to fully prevent edits to those changes after the fact (read more here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/change-logging/#detailed-logging) - Good luck!